# Using Handler to keep track of files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently working on a website which is being developed using Asp.Net and C#. I'm making use of `Asp.Net Handler` to allow users to download files. I can download the files no problem. However I need to log which files were downloaded successfully. This part doesn't seem to work correctly for me. E.g. if I click on the file to download and then click cancel on the browser prompt my code still writes to the log. I can't seem to figure out how can I write to log **only** when the file has successfully downloaded.

My Code is below.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string logFilePath = "PathToMyLogFile";
    string filePath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(context.Request.QueryString["file"]);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

    if (context.Response.IsClientConnected) //Shouldn't this tell me if the client is connected or not?
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(logFilePath, true))
        {
            if (!File.Exists(logFilePath))
            {
                //Create log file if one does not exist
                File.Create(logFilePath);
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteLine("The following file was downloaded \"{0}\" on {1}", fileName, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    context.Response.End();
}
```

I appreciate all your help and support.

Comment: You are logging if the user is connected during a file download, you don't have anything in there about successful download. Yes, that tells you if the client is connected, however it doesn't tell you if the file is downloaded. I don't think you get any kind of response for that, since the client can stop a stream anytime it wants.

Comment: @RonBeyer Would you know what would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: I think you can only log that the file was requested to be downloaded, I'm not sure you can know if it succeeded or not on the client side. You may be able to do it with some sort of AJAX and javascript on the client side, download the file and send a success message to the server, somebody with more experience in web dev may have to chime in.

Comment: I don't think there's any way of knowing whether the client has successfully received all the file when using plain HTTP.

Comment: I belive if you use Response.OutputStream.Write instead of WriteFile, you will get HttpException(The remote host closed the connection exception on client disconnect/cancel) may be WriteFile also fails, but this need to be checked

Comment: As @RonBeyer said using `$.ajax`we can do it .and on `success` you can trigger the log to the server. if you are intrested i would give you an example

Comment: @Webruster If you can provide an example that would highly appreciated

Comment: @Code sorry for late reply, For the bytes downloaded (when get info with the `xhr.responseText`), it's a little more difficult, because the browser doesn't know how many bytes will send the server request. The only thing that browser knows in this case is the size of bytes it's receiving. But there is a solution for this, it's sufficient to set a `Content-Length` header on the server script so to give the size of bytes the browser is receiving. for more info go to[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_XMLHttpRequest) and on complettion of the download, just update the `flag` to server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried create simple handler which can detect the download was canceled/broken from server-side perspective.

The important part is "context.Response.IsClientConnected" during/after the sending data.

This example will send neverending file with random data. You can test it in all browser, how exactly they will behave. I tested it only in Chrome.

```
/// <summary>
/// Writes random data.
/// </summary>
public class NeverendingFile : IHttpHandler {
    public bool IsReusable {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.Buffer = false;
        context.Response.BufferOutput = false;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"Neverendingfile.dat\"");
        context.Response.Flush();

        // flag used for debuging, in production it will be always false => writing into output stream will nevere ends
        var shouldStop = false;
        for(var i = 0; !shouldStop; i++) {
            // chunk contains random data
            var chunk = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();

            for (var a = 0; a < 1000; a++) {
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(chunk, 0, chunk.Length);
            }
            context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
            // sleep is just for slowing the download
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

            if (!context.Response.IsClientConnected) {
                // the download was canceled or broken
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Edited source code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    string logFilePath = "PathToLogFile";
    //Determine the file path
    string filePath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(context.Request.QueryString["file"]);
    //Determine the file name
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

    context.Response.Buffer = false;
    context.Response.BufferOutput = false;
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    context.Response.Flush();
    context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();

    if (!context.Response.IsClientConnected) {
        // the download was canceled or broken
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(logFilePath, true)) {
            if (!File.Exists(logFilePath)) {
                //Create log file if one does not exist
                File.Create(logFilePath);
            }
            else {
                writer.WriteLine("The Download was canceled");
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    context.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: since you're using `context.Response.IsClientConnected`, do you still need to leverage the `context.Response.OutputStream` ?

Comment: I'm curious as to whether you'd still get `context.Response.IsClientConnected` returning true after a file has finished downloading (I suspect not unless a keep-alive is used) - this sample doesn't really provide a definitive answer as it's going to keep generating a file - a better test would be to end the file after a few hundred MB have been downloaded or so.

Comment: @RobertFoster - the client don't know, you finished the sending file. That is the reason why "context.Response.IsClientConnected" will be "true".

Comment: Your code is technically interesting, but IMHO you should give the OP an example that matches his needs (you're not far from it I suppose). Note these techniques (streaming manually the file in .NET, or using WriteFile) are far from being optimal in terms of server performance (vs a call to response.TransmitFile - not WriteFile - that uses kernel cache + an acknowledge from the client - like others proposed)

Comment: @TcKs Sorry, but how would I use this with my requirement?

Comment: @Code Check for "context.Response.IsClientConnected" before "context.Response.End()".

Comment: @TcKs I still get the same issue, The name gets written even after hitting cancel button

Comment: @Code the problem is, the check for "IsClientConnected" must be AFTER the "WriteFile()" and BEFORE the "Response.End()". And after the "WriteFile()" you want call "Flush" because of possible buffers on the server side.

Comment: @TcKs I've tried what you suggested in the comment but still the same issue.. can you provide an example with my code please

Comment: @Code I fixed the code. I tested it in Chrome and Firefox. It works both with "Cancel" in save dialog and "Cancel" during downloading. If you still don't see the logs in file, check if the logging is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that both download and cancel buttons are on same page.
I created the following example to check if the file is already started download while canceling using a singleton class that have a flag "isFileDownload" so that the flag value wont be initialized for every request for the same user.

1. Everytime a request comes from user, assign "isFileDownload" json
   variable to the "isFileDownload" of singleton class.
2. When a file download request comes to handler, the "isFileDownload" of singleton will be set to true. while sending the response back to the user, check if "isFileDownload" true den log else dont.
3. if user clicks download button then "isFileDownload" =  true and user clicks cancel button before the file is downloaded then "isFileDownload" = false.
4. Since "isFileDownload" property is part of the singleton class, same instance will be updated.

**FYI,** i am new to handlers.Sorry in advance if I missed something to take into account while posting this

**Handler Class:**

```
public class DownloadFile : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string fileName = @"test.txt";
        string filePath = context.Server.MapPath("/test.txt");
        string logFilePath = context.Server.MapPath("/Log.txt");
        //string filePath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(context.Request.QueryString["file"]);
        //string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        Singleton s = Singleton.Instance;
        s.isFileDownload = Convert.ToBoolean(context.Request.Form["isFileDownload"]);
        if (context.Response.IsClientConnected) //Shouldn't this tell me if the client is connected or not?
        {

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(logFilePath,true))
            {
                if (!File.Exists(logFilePath))
                {
                    //Create log file if one does not exist
                    File.Create(logFilePath);
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("The following file was downloaded \"{0}\" on {1}", fileName, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                    writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }

        //To mock the large file download
        if (s.isFileDownload)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

        if (context.Response.IsClientConnected )
        {
            if (s.isFileDownload){
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
            context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
            context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
            context.Response.End();
        }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }


    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Singleton class:** [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static volatile Singleton instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    private Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                        instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public bool isFileDownload { get; set; }
}
```

**Html Page :**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var isFileDownload = false;
        $("#download").click(function () {
            isFileDownload = true;
            console.log(isFileDownload);
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "DownloadFile.ashx",
                data: { isFileDownload:true }
            }).done(function (data) {
                alert(data);
               
            });
        });

        $("#cancel").click(function () {
            if (isFileDownload) {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "DownloadFile.ashx",
                    data: { isFileDownload: false }
                }).done(function (data) {
                    alert("canceld");
                    isFileDownload = false;
                });
            }
        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
            isFileDownload = false;
        });
)};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<button type="button" value="DownLoad" id="download" title="Download">Download</button>
<button type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancel" title="Cancel">Cancel</button>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The buttons in questions are of the browser pop when the user selects the file to download. There's no cancel button on my actual website

Answer (score 0):

When the browser popup appears, it means that the server has begun to send(stream) the data to the client. You cannot detect in reality whether the file download was successful or not.
You can only detect how many bytes was sent out to the client and if the byte count equals the file length, you can *assume* that the client was able to download the file, but you cannot get a proof that the file was successfully saved on the client's machine/environment.

Example: if i am downloading under linux and forward the stream to /dev/null, you will see that i have downloaded the file, but in reality the file won't exist on my machine.